# Needing help to know exactly where to place the HTML code?

Tags: html

I need to know exactly where to place the HTML code. I am putting (Credit Card logos) into the overall theme of my website with "Big Cartel." I need to put the code below my Copyright. I also have provided the Credit Card logo HTML code. could someone show me exactly where to type it in to make it work.

I know that the HTML code goes at the bottom below my Copyright, I typed that in after support showed me where to place it. But the new (Credit Card Logos)HTML code I need someone to show me.

The following HTML code is my websites code, where I need to place the (Credit Card Logos) I was told to place the (Credit Card Logos) below my Copyright. I just need to know exactly where to type it in and what that would look like. Also note below the website code is the new!(Credit Card Logos)HTML code. Could someone combine the two showing me where the new code goes.

```
  <a href="{{ store.website }}" class="button back-to-site" class="button">Back to site</a>
      {% endif %}
      <div id="badge"> <font size="2"> &copy; {{ 'Today' | date: '%Y' }} Bellaiam. All Rights Reserved.</div>  
      <!--<div class="badge">{{ bigcartel_credit }}</div>-->  
    </nav>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ 'api' | theme_js_url }}"></script>
<script src="{{ theme | theme_js_url }}"></script>
```

---

they will not allow me to post a picture. So the HTML for the (Credit Card Logos)are at. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/logos-marks/
at the bottom on the left hand side. PayPal, MasterCard, Visa, Discover, Amex.

Expected result is that some kind person with way more know how will combine the (Credit Card Logo) HTML code with my website HTML code to show me how and where I need to type the complete code in, and under my Copyright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering each of the credit cards are all combined into a single image, you simply need to include this image *directly* below your copyright `<div>` in your above code:

```
<div id="badge"> <font size="2"> &copy; {{ 'Today' | date: '%Y' }} Bellaiam. All Rights Reserved.</div>
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/cc-badges-ppmcvdam.png" alt="Credit Card Badges">
```

Note that this will *insert* the images into your page directly below your footer, though you may need to position them -- this would be achieved with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). For example, if you want to center them, you would apply `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto`.

Also note that the `<font>` tag is [obsolete](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-font-tag.html), and you should be using CSS for text styling instead. You can control the size of the font with the CSS property [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).

Comment: Worked perfect but how could I drop it down just a bit so the Copyright text does not touch it? 10: 45PM  Thank you Obsidian Age.